# Reverse a Byte in a two Byte long variable

Tags: c, types, casting

I have a two Byte variable where I want to reverse the bits of the MSB Byte.

I'm using this function to reverse a Byte:

```
uint8_t reverse_bits(uint8_t a){

    return ((a & 0x1)  << 7) | ((a & 0x2)  << 5) |
           ((a & 0x4)  << 3) | ((a & 0x8)  << 1) |
           ((a & 0x10) >> 1) | ((a & 0x20) >> 3) |
           ((a & 0x40) >> 5) | ((a & 0x80)  >> 7);
}
```

I wrote this function to receive my variable and reverse the second Byte:

```
uint16_t reverseByte(uint16_t b){

    uint16_t b0 ;

    uint16_t b1 ;
    uint8_t revb;
    uint8_t retb ;
    b0 =  b & 0x00FF;
    b1 = b & 0xFF00;
    revb = b1 >> 8;
    retb = reverse_bits(revb);
    b1 = retb;
    b1 =  b1 << 8;

    return (b1 + b0);
}
```

I get the error **Conflicting  Types for reverseByte**  at the first line of the function.

How do I correct it ? I know the code is far from being elegant , I just need a quick fix.

Thank you!

Comment: Not directly related, but you are using `revb` before it is initialized.

Comment: And on which line __exactly__ do you get the error? Please read this: [mcve].

Comment: Are you declaring the function after you use it?

Answer (score 0):

The Problem was in the declaration of the function. I used it before declaring it, at least in my case.

I initialized the local variables too to get rid of the warnings

Thanks for the hints. I don't understand the vote down though.

Comment: The downvote (BTW not from me) is probably because there was not enough information in the question.